# Как перезагрузить страницу сервера со стороны клиента

Tags: php, javascript

На сервере при каждой загрузке страницы генерируются пароли и записываются в переменные:

```
echo "var password1 = '$password1';
var password2 = '$password2';
var password3 = '$password3';
var password4 = '$password4';
var password5 = '$password5';
var password6 = '$password6';
var password7 = '$password7';
var password8 = '$password8';
var password9 = '$password9';
var password10 = '$password10';";
```

На клиенте эти переменные записываются в input'ы:

```
function updatePasswordAtPage()
{
    $('#passwordInput').val(password1);
    $('#passwordInput2').val(password2);
    $('#passwordInput3').val(password3);
    $('#passwordInput4').val(password4);
    $('#passwordInput5').val(password5);
    $('#passwordInput6').val(password6);
    $('#passwordInput7').val(password7);
    $('#passwordInput8').val(password8);
    $('#passwordInput9').val(password9);
    $('#passwordInput10').val(password10);

}
```

На клиенте есть `onclick="updatePasswordAtPage()"`при нажатии на которую каждый раз должны записываться новые пароли, но проблема в том что код на сервере выполняется всего один раз и новые пароли не генерируются.

Можно ли как нибудь реализовать перезагрузку страницы после выполнения кода на сервере или сделать как нибудь вызов функции генерирования на сервере со стороны клиента. не знаю что делать в общем

Comment: Используйте AJAX + API.

Comment: Если совсем уж просто, то вставьте в `updatePasswordAtPage()` одну строчку: `window.location.reload();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Генерируйте на сервере JSON, где каждый ключ - ид элемента на странице, а значение - пароль.
С клиента отправляйте запрос через AJAX на обработчик, парсите JSON и перебирайте по порядку.
Например, так:

PHP handler

```
<?php
    echo json_encode(["passwordInput4" => "что-то", "passwordInput2" => "что-то"]);
?>
```

JS:

```
function updatePasswordAtPage () {
      fetch('/url/to/handler.php')
        .then((r) => r.json())
        .then(r => Object.keys(r).forEach(k => $("#" + k).val(r[k])))
}
```